# Vanilla Gnome on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, customization

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, the whole design is suddenly broken. There's an ugly tinge or orange everwhere, the dock is visible all the time (not only when in overview mode) and basically everything I used to love about the Gnome desktop is gone :-(

I tried various means of getting the vanilla Gnome experience back but nothing has worked:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-default-settings
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-default-settings vanilla-gnome-desktop
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css # (and then I selected gnome-shell.css)
```

None of this got rid of the permanent dock and when logged out I don't see a 'gear' icon to switch to Gnome on X.org.

Any ideas how to get rid of the Ubuntu modifications?

Comment: Turns out the 'secret' to having the 'gear icon' is that you need to switch of auto-login. With auto-login the icon simply won't show up, even if you deliberately log out and see the log-in screen.

Answer (score 3):

It would be more predictable if you install other meta-package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then logout and login back to *GNOME* or *GNOME on Xorg* session.

Answer (score 2):

Did you restart your computer yet? The GNOME session option showed up for me only after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Gnome Tweaks and then simply turn off the Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: Ubuntu Dock is a system extension, cannot be *easily* turned off using GNOME Tweaks.